# Multiple dimension scale development - validation using SEM

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, scale-construction

I'm developing a scale for measuring customer experience. Based on the principal component analysis I established that it has three components (11 items). Now I need to validate it by relating it to customer satisfaction and loyalty scores using SEM (like in study 6 in Brakus, J. J., Schmitt, B. H., & Zarantonello, L. (2009). Brand experience: what is it? How is it measured? Does it affect loyalty?. Journal of marketing, 73(3), 52-68.).
I have no clue how to combine the three components into one experience score that I can later correlate with satisfaction and loyalty scores. Right now I did the following:

- created a new variable - sum of the items for each component
- multiplied that by the score from principal component analysis

`model <- ' # measurement model
            Experience =~  TC1*Component1 + TC2*Component2 + TC3*Component3
            # regressions
            satisfaction ~ Experience 
            loyalty ~ Experience '
fit <- sem(model, data=df)`

My questions: 
How do I combine the three components from my PCA to get the Experience score? Is the way I included the factor scores correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Questions are: How do I combine the three components from my PCA to get the Experience score? Is the way I included the factor scores correct?
Sorry for missing them at first.

Answer (score 0):

See this 2022 Journal of Retailing article for the most latest procedural information on [scale development](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jretai.2022.03.003). This is an open-access article.

Start with Table 1, which provides an overview of all the steps that the authors have conducted in this [customer experience](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jretai.2022.03.003) scale development study.

To answer the specific question (i.e., how to combine scores from component/factors to get an overall experience score), this study has developed the overall omnichannel customer experience construct (i.e., OCX) a higher-order composite model. They have used SmartPLS for assessing the structural model.

The article also provides an extensive web appendix with procedural information.